# Sales and tip calculator

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

I previously posted a code with the similar way and I am still having problems with it. this time I get `100.0712.5` when I put `10` as the bill, `7` for the sales tax and `25` for the tip. I am really new to Javascript coding and I have literally been spending hours trying to figure this out I need help.

```
<html> 
<head> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function applyTax(){ 


  var inputAmount = document.getElementById( 'dollars' ).value; 
  var salesTax = document.getElementById( 'tax' ).value;
  var tip = document.getElementById( 'tip' ).value; 
  var totalAmount = (salesTax/100) + (inputAmount);
  var tipprcnt = (tip/100) * (inputAmount);
  var Grandtotal = (inputAmount + (totalAmount*1) + (tipprcnt*1));

  //document.getElementById( 'requestedAmount' ).innerHTML = tipprcnt; 
  //document.getElementById( 'requestedTax' ).innerHTML = totalAmount;
  document.getElementById( 'requestedGrand' ).innerHTML = Grandtotal; 
} 

</script> 

</head> 
<body> 

<h1>Sales Tax + Tip Calculator</h1>
<p>Type in your price (dollar amount). Click the &quot;Calculate&quot; button to receive your total.
</p>
<p>
  What is the bill amount?: $<input type="text" id="dollars" /> <br>
  What is the sales tax?:<input type="text" id="tax" />%<br>
  how much do you want to tip?:<input type="text" id="tip" />% 
  <input type="button" onclick="applyTax();" value="Calculate" /> 

</p>
</h2>The Grand Total is:</h2>
<div id="requestedAmount"> </div> 
<div id="requestedTax"> </div> 
<div id="requestedGrand"> </div>
<p><a href="http://jasonhuang.myweb.usf.edu/lis4365/index.html">Home</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You're adding the tax to the input amount instead of multiplying by it.

Comment: @Bijan He's doing that so that it will be converted from a string to a number, so that `+` will do addition rather than concatenation. Except that the one that needs to be converted is `inputAmount`.

Answer (score 0):

You were adding them as string, use `parseFloat` instead

http://plnkr.co/edit/6pN2Ug5qxcOSUjE5AnhJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
function applyTax(){ 
  var inputAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById( 'dollars' ).value); 
  var salesTax = parseFloat(document.getElementById( 'tax' ).value);
  var tip = parseFloat(document.getElementById( 'tip' ).value); 
  var taxprcnt = (salesTax/100) * (inputAmount);
  var tipprcnt = (tip/100) * (inputAmount);
  var Grandtotal = inputAmount + taxprcnt + tipprcnt;

  document.getElementById( 'requestedGrand' ).innerHTML = Grandtotal.toFixed(2); // Round to 2 decimals
}
```

1. You should use `parseFloat()` to convert the inputs to numbers.
2. You need to multiply the input amount by the tax percentage, not add them.
3. You should round off the final result, because people don't want to see fractional pennies.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9sv25edz/)

When I enter $10 amount, 7% tax, 25% tip, the total is $13.20.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Number(input.value)` by every input to convert the string values into numbers. You can use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat` instead of `Number()` if you want. The first converts to integer, the second converts to numbers with decimal points.

Btw forget the overusage of `()` and `*1`, it is just noise for others...

Your variable names are confusing, but I guess you wanted something like this:

```
var amountInput = document.getElementById("dollars");
var taxInput = document.getElementById("tax");
var tipInput = document.getElementById("tip");

var amount = Number(amountInput.value);
var taxPercent = Number(taxInput.value);
var tipPercent = Number(tipInput.value);

var grandTotal = Math.round(amount * (100 + taxPercent + tipPercent)) / 100;

var grandTotalOutput = document.getElementById("requestedGrand");
grandTotalOutput.innerHTML = grandTotal;
```